# Ngnix Location Alias directive always returning 404

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want when someone access http://abhinav.epaper.lc/media then he should get contents from /home/ankurgupta/websites/lc/uploads/abhinav.epaper.lc/

But http://abhinav.epaper.lc/media/a.jpg always returns 404 error.
But a.jpg is present in /home/ankurgupta/websites/lc/uploads/abhinav.epaper.lc/a.jpg

Here is the configuration:

```
server {


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name abhinav.epaper.lc;
    root /home/ankurgupta/websites/lc;  
    index index.php;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }   
    location /media {
        alias /home/ankurgupta/websites/lc/uploads/abhinav.epaper.lc;
    }   
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include nginxconfig.io/php_fastcgi.conf;
    }
    include nginxconfig.io/general.conf;
}
```

nginxconfig.io/general.conf;

```
# security headers
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;

 . files
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}

# assets, media
location ~* \.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv)$ {
    expires 7d;
    access_log off;
}

# svg, fonts
location ~* \.(?:svgz?|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff2?)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    expires 7d;
    access_log off;
}

# gzip
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/xml+rss application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;
```

nginxconfig.io/php_fastcgi.conf;

```
# default fastcgi_params
include fastcgi_params;

# fastcgi settings
fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index                   index.php;
fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT     $realpath_root;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE   "open_basedir=$base/:/usr/lib/php/:/tmp/";

fastcgi_intercept_errors        off;
fastcgi_buffer_size             128k;
fastcgi_buffers                 256 16k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size       256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size    256k;
```

Comment: Have you checked the error log? Have you checked file and directory permissions?

Comment: All folder and files are owned by www-data:www-data .
Folder permissions: drwxrwxr-x
File permissions -rw-r--r--

Comment: It works if I use the following configuration:

location ~/media(.+) {     
  alias /home/ankurgupta/websites/lc/uploads/abhinav.epaper.lc/$1;   
 }

Comment: In that case, I would suspect that there is a conflicting `location` hidden inside `nginxconfig.io/general.conf`.

Comment: I have updated the question with other file contents. Please check them.

Comment: I noticed that if I comment out this line: location ~* \.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv)$ {
 expires 7d;
 access_log off;
}
then alias starts working. What is wrong in this block?

Comment: The `location` following `# assets, media` will look for `.jpg` files under the main document root. This is due to the way in which `location` statements are evaluated. Use `location ^~ /media` or use a *regular expression* `location`

Answer (score 0):

Removing the following lines fixed the problem

location ~* .(?:css(.map)?|js(.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv)$ {
    expires 7d;
    access_log off;
}